# I am having trouble importing data into my GeoServer workspace, receiving "InsufficientAuthentication error, cannot access workspace as 'anonymous'"

Tags: geoserver, workspace

I am having trouble importing data into my workspace in GeoSever. I am able to create various data stores, however I cannot import data into them anymore from any source including PostGIS. I keep receiving the following error(refer to image below). This error occurs with any workspace I create, I am unable to load data into any workspace; GeoServer keeps reading my role as anonymous, but I have a user role.

Can anyone offer any suggestions/help? I was able to load data before and all of sudden it has stopped working for me 3 weeks ago, and I believe it is a configuration issue, but am unsure how to fix it.

[image]